# CSS spacing divs precisely

Tags: css

I have 3 Divs that I want to have precisely spaced to line up under some images. I've tried fiddling with floating them and using margin, but I don't know how to get to the point where I can specify a number of pixels to be from the left margin.

```
<div class="cont1" style="margin-left:100px; float:left;"> label </div>
<div class="cont2" style="margin-left:200px; float:left;"> label </div>
<div class="cont3" style="margin-left:300px;"> label </div>
```

Using float:left seems to screw up a lot of the spacing. Without it, the spacing is right but each div is on a new line instead of a single line.

Comment: why you don't use `float:left` for the last `div`?

Comment: You may need to set `margin-right:0` and `padding:0` to ensure no additional spacing is messing things up.

Comment: Can you post any more relevant code? When using float:left; the margin-left will be calculated from the element to the left, so the second div will be 200px to the left of the first, and the third will be 300px to the left of the second. Only the first element will be spaced from the container. You could always wrap these three <div>s in a container <div> that has relative positioning and then give them absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you expect the second div `cont2` to be 200 pixels from the left side of the window, when in fact it will be 200 pixels from the left of the first div.

If that's what you want, you should be using absolute positioning instead:

```
.cont1 {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.cont2 {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.cont3 {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vZK7N/1/

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is a block level element so `float: left;` is a great way to get them to sit side by side.

As far as spacing is concerned, your margins will be much smaller after the elements are floated because each `<div>` will be positioned *after* the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Span instead of div, it may work. Div will be always align in new row.